# Edit subject line of received email in Thunderbird 3.0

Tags: email, thunderbird

Is there a way to edit the subject line of emails you've received in Thunderbird? I use email a lot for work and it would be a lot easier if I could change subjects to make things easier to find later.

I found a plug-in but it only works for Thunderbird up to 2.0 and I'd rather not have to downgrade to get this feature.

Comment: I hate that most of my colleagues send blank-subject emails 99% of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the message to Drafts, edit Subject, move message back.

Comment: that replaced the original sender with oneself and updates the message date though...

Comment: Technically this works, but it alters other things in the email to such as the sender, so isn't an option.

Answer (score 2):

The [Edit Email Subject](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/edit-email-subject/?src=search) extension does this (but [it won't sync IMAP](https://superuser.com/questions/357575/is-there-a-thunderbird-plugin-to-modify-imap-emails))

Comment: Yes, it will sync IMAP, as of New Year's.  There's a configuration option.  You have to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

**TB Header Tools Extension (add-on)**

this thunderbird add-on lets you change any header or the email's source. I use it with TB 3.1.9 to add subjects to those awful blank-subject emails ...

For a description/discussion of this add-on see:

http://forum.addonsmirror.net/index.php?showtopic=1906&st=0&gopid=38064&#entry38064

Note: if you are using TB 3.1.x, make sure you get the patched version. The unpatched add-on will install, but won't show the edit dialog.

Comment: Dead link I'm afraid.

Comment: Try [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/header-tools-lite/)

Answer (score 0):

I use Thunderbird to connect to my Gmail account (via IMAPS); but for gritty email stuff, I use '[Mutt](http://www.mutt.org)'; also via IMAPS. It's text based, (which takes a little getting used to initially), but extremely powerful. If you really need something graphical, than the '[Edit Email Subject](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/edit-email-subject/?src=search)' Thunderbird plug-in already mentioned is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and made a video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yh0lUL9sOdg
You can easily edit any part of the email - dates, sender, subject, etc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).