# Is there a thunderbird plugin to modify IMAP emails?

Tags: thunderbird, plugins, imap

Sometimes I receive emails with subjects like "As discussed" or "(empty)". At that point I know what it is about but for later reference I'd like to change the subject into something slightly more useful. The emails are accessed via IMAP, thunderbird can basically modify them (as the detach attachments feature shows), so is there a way to modify the subject line as well?

**edit** saving a modified draft is not what I want, since that changes the sender to myself and the date to the modification date

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/110983/edit-subject-line-of-received-email-in-thunderbird-3-0 (the edit Draft solution is not helping me since it modifies the sender and the date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two other add-ons that may possibly do the job :

[TB Header Tools Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/tb-header-tools-extension/)
This extension hasn’t been updated for years. However [here is a way](http://www.dezertdezine.com/blog/thunderbird-changing-email-headers) to get it working again.

[HeaderToolsLite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/header-tools-lite/)
Has an option for forcing changes with IMAP accounts.

Comment: +1 for pointing towards HeaderToolsLite. Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 4):

I use the [EditEmailSubject](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/edit-email-subject/?src=search) extension, works great for me.

Comment: hey thanks, it looks good. Unfortunately it does not seem to sync back to the IMAP server though, i.e. when I access a renamed email from another machine, the renaming is undone. This also happens when moving edited mails to other folders. But +1 since it might work nicely for POP3 at least

Comment: That's true, this is a weakness of this addon.

Comment: Maybe a bounty will motivate someone to modify it :-7

Comment: Not needed.  As of New Year's, it works! (You just have to enable the IMAP option.)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what your asking, however....

If you click **Reply** you can change the subject to whatever you want, and then save it as a draft.  The drafts would sync, and you'd be able to sort your drafts by subject that you give them.

Comment: thanks, but I want to change the subject stored in a _received_ email without modifying anything else. The drafts trick will put me in as sender and change the mail's date to "now", making things just as bad as a useless mail subject

Comment: What you doing can't be done.  You can't (legally) fool your mail server into thinking a subject is something it isn't, while still retaining the original [message headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Message_header).  

I would suggest catagorizing them using labels like [this](http://images.macworld.com/images/reviews/graphics/132647-thunderbird_labels_586.jpg) and [this](http://www.mixthenet.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/gmail3.png)

Comment: I don't want to retain the original message headers. And a modified version of an email can be stored on an IMAP server, as the native thunderbird possibility to remove (or detach) attachments shows

Comment: What mail server are you using?

Comment: My university runs [horde/IMP](http://www.horde.org/apps/imp), but from what I read in the context of the [TB Header Tools Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/tb-header-tools-extension/) mentioned in [harrymc's answer](http://superuser.com/q/360817/35237), it should also work on gmail and probably any other IMAP server - why are you asking?

Comment: Are you looking for something that works with Gmail?  If you are, I think you'd find and answer faster.

Comment: no, IMAP servers in general, especially horde/IMP but I don't see why this shouldn't apply to _any_ IMAP service